# How to call php file on same page on click of link

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am new to php & would like to call another php file on the same file in the div tag. 
on the home page i am calling the php file & have link on those files & want to open the result of that link below in the div tag. 
I want to dispaly the result of all the links in the div tag

Please Help !

Thanks in advance

**ViewBdd.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
                mysqli_select_db($con,"csdata");
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
              FROM `data`");

                echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' style='border:black; ' align='center'>
                            <tr><th colspan='4'>(BDD-2015)</th></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th id='td'>Customer Name</th>  
                                <th id='td'>Rs. in Lakhs</th>
                                <th id='td'>Metric Ton</th>
                                <th id='td'>Percentage</th>
                            </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='sku.php?Customer_name=" . $row['Customer_name'] . "'>" . $row['Customer_name'] . "</a></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . round($row['Total'],2) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . round($row['MT'],2) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . round($row['Percentage'],2) . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sku.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
                mysqli_select_db($con,"csdata");
                $name=$_GET['Customer_name'];
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from `data` ");

                echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' style='border:black; ' align='center'>
                            <tr>
                                <th id='td'>Customer Name</th>
                                <th id='td'>Item Name</th>
                                <th id='td'>Rs. in Lakhs</th>
                                <th id='td'>Metric Ton</th>
                            </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['Customer_Name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['Item_Grouping'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . round($row['Amount'],2) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . round($row['MT'],2) . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting output of all the queries. I just need to place the result in the respective div tag on click of the links given

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need Ajax to achieve that.

Comment: Sir can you help in this

Comment: I agree with @Zsw, you need XHR (natively) or AJAX (in jQuery) to achieve this. You should leave an empty div on your main page, then you should retrieve other page's content on click via XHR and put contents of this response into the div you created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call another PHP script without refreshing a page you have to use AJAX

1. Look throught this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp
2. Easiest way to use AJAX (imho) is usage of jQuery. Here is another tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

As for your code:

1. You have to place a link inside you div's
2. Attach an event listener to all these links
3. Call an AJAX request inside this event listener
4. Render output result of AJAX request into your html

Some changes to your code:

1. Instead of

use

```
<div class="sales"><a href="SalesBdd.php" class="get_result"></a></div>
```

2. Then add

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

to home.php

3. Then add to home.php script

   ```
   $('.get_result').click(function (event) 
   { 
      event.preventDefault(); 

      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $.get(url, function(data) {
         $('.sales').html(data);
      });
   });
   ```

As a result then you press link, the resulting html (which is get from php page) will be placed instead of link into div.

Comment: Sir i have never used AJAX or JQuery! If you can give me a dummy example for this .

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Could you paste somethere you code?

Comment: What error did you get? Also you have to put some text inside <a href tag

Comment: Sir it;s taking me to new page !

Comment: Update you code please, event.preventDefault(); in event listener must prevent redirection to a new page

Answer (score 0):

HTML frames are used to solved your problem, whice is user to divide your browser window into multiple sections where each section can load a separate HTML document. A collection of frames in the browser window is known as a frameset. The window is divided into frames in a similar way the tables are organized: into rows and columns.

So you try to use Frame concept Instead writing more than one html tag within one page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
       <title>HTML Frames</title>
     </head>
  <frameset rows="10%,80%,10%">
        <frame name="top" src="abc.html" />
        <frame name="main" src="xyz.html" />
        <frame name="bottom" src="abcd.html" />
    <noframes>
      <body>
        Your browser does not support frames.
      </body>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
 </html>
```

The above  example to create three horizontal frames.

If you want to create all the frames vertically, change the line as

```
<frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
```

Comment: Now if i have link suppsoe in frame top & i want to display the solution in frame bottom then how can i do that ?

Comment: Then you should use AJAX concept. You just refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp